# React Slick is throwing error in responsive mode in browser

Tags: reactjs, slider, carousel, slick.js, react-slick

I am using [react-slick](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-slick). In my settings, I have `swipeToSlide` set as true. Whenever, I swipe the slider to the right or left by pressing the left mouse button, I get this error when responsive mode is on:

> Unable to preventDefault inside passive event listener invocation.

I don't get this error when responsive mode in browser is switched off. Already tried this:

```
.slick-list, .slick-track { touch-action:...; }
```

How can I resolve this error and why it is happening in responsive mode only?

Comment: can you share the settings config of react slick

Comment: const settings = {
  slidesToShow:1,
  swipeToSlide: true
}

Comment: Where is your breakpoint for the responsive.

Comment: Doesn't matter. Just switch on the responsive mode(toggle device toolbar) and then swipe the slider, it will throw this error.

Comment: issue is fixed in react-slick 0.28.0 version